# Component Not Loading with VueRouter Locally. Works in Production

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

Sorry if this an easy question, but I temporarily inherited an app written in node.js / express and a Vue 2.5.2 frontend. I cannot get a specific route to work locally in my test environment that works in the live environment.

Say we've emailed a user a link. When they click on it, it's supposed to open this specific Vue component. But it just loads the home page; 200 status.

Here's the relevant part in the node/express SPA:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.render('index.ejs', { has_token: false });
    });

  app.get('/token/:token', (req, res) => {
    return res.render('index.ejs', { has_token: true });
  });
```

It sets the `has_token` variable. Here is the relevant Vue part in the SPA:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    LandingPage,
    Register,
    Home
  },
  router,
  store,
  created() {

    if(has_token) {
      console.log('has token'); # WE MAKE IT HERE
      this.$router.push('/TokenRegistration');
    }
 ...
 ...
```

Here is a snippet of the routes created

```
const routes = [
    {
        name: '/',
        path: '/',
        component: LandingPage
    },
  {
    name: 'Register',
    path: '/Register',
    component: Register
  },
  {
    name: 'TokenRegistration',
    path: '/TokenRegistration',
    component: TokenRegistration
  },
```

And them being loaded

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
});
```

Sorry if this is an easy question, but I haven't used node, express or VueRouter before, and this is the only thing stumping me. I double checked and made sure both environments have their repos in sync and rebuilt the app and reboot the node service just in case.

Summary:

- In production, I go to `.com/token/<some string>` it loads the specified component `TokenRegistration`.
- In local dev, I go to `.com/token/<some string>` it just loads the home page `LandingPage` Component

And there are no JS errors; page load 200 success.

Comment: Please specify which OS you are using in prod/local environment

Comment: @macghriogair Ubuntu 16.04. Locally a vagrant box.

Comment: Seems like there is some navigation guard in the project. Search for router.before in your src folder. May be that gives some direction?

Comment: That absolutely does, thank you. If you would like to post this as an answer, I'll accept it. He put in some hacky before router methods... :-\

Comment: It helps a lot. I removed the beforeEach on the router, and it shows the form I expect for a split second then redirects again. So I gotta track that down, but a bit closer!